# Simple RNN fit dimension

Tags: python, recurrent-neural-network

I'm in trouble with an error from the following code:

```
import time
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random as rd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
#from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.layers.recurrent import SimpleRNN
#from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
#from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve

series_X=pd.read_csv("novo.csv", header=0)
X, y=train_test_split(series_X, test_size=0.25)
#Define Model
seed=2019
rd.seed(seed)
fit1=Sequential()

fit1.add(SimpleRNN(output_dim=1, activation='tanh', input_shape=(7500,1)))

fit1.add(Dense(output_dim=1, activation='linear'))

sgd=SGD(lr=0.01)

fit1.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd)

fit1.fit(X, y, batch_size=10, nb_epoch=10)
```

The error output is as follows:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected simple_rnn_23_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (7500, 1)
```

I know that this problem is already posted but I can't solve it yet.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are feeding your model a 3 dimensions input yet you have declared input_shape to be 2d, you should try something like this :

```
fit1.add(SimpleRNN(output_dim=1, activation='tanh', input_shape=x.shape)))
```

by the way your code is completly wrong, i see variables that has never been declared like training and test, and the fit function should take first argument the input which in your case is x and the second is the ouput or y

```
fit1.fit(x, y, batch_size=10, nb_epoch=10,validation_data=[x_test,y_test])
```

Comment: Ok my friend. I've made the mistake of copying it wrong. But the errors are not from the undeclared variables. Thank you for your answer.